# Horizontally align table cell element

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell element Im trying to align horizontally and vertically but I'm only managing to get 1 to work and thats the vertical alignment.

The images have no set size so it has to be fluid and work with a max-height, width...

**CSS**

```
.prod-img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px; 
  border:1px solid black;
}
.prod-img a {
  max-width: 170px;
  height: 150px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.prod-img img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mjx4xvgj/1/

Comment: Use: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjx4xvgj/2/)

Comment: Im assuming by align you mean center horizontally and vertically? Any particular reason you need it to be displayed as a table cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using correct `display`:

- Using `margin: auto` and `display: block` for `<a>`.
- Using `display: inline-block` for `<img />`

**Code:**

```
.prod-img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px; border:1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.prod-img a {
  max-width: 170px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
}
.prod-img img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1zLLasfw/**

Comment: :(  doesn't vertically align for me in firefox.

Comment: @Aaron It vertically aligns now. Sorry. Can you check and remove the downvote please?

Comment: Awesome Praveen, couldn't see the wood for the trees! thanks

Comment: It was my downvote. Not necessary after your fix, so removed. But the use of `vertical-align:middle` in the answer is rather scattergun. The only one necessary is the one on `.prod-img img`

Comment: @Alohci Thanks for letting me know and correcting me. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Just change your CSS with the following, you got your output:

```
.prod-img {
    display: table;
    margin: 20px; border:1px solid black;
    width : 100%;
}
.prod-img a {
    max-width: 170px;
    height: 150px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.prod-img img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

use this in style may help you

```
.prod-img {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: table;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
.prod-img a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```